# JAVA: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java, types, concatenation

I have written the following piece that is supposed to print time in the format of hh:ss:mm.
I get the following error when trying to concat an int, but only for the last statement, which is strange. (_hour & _minute & _second methods return an int)

```
public String toString()
{
    String TimeString = null;

    if(this._hour < 10){
        TimeString = "0" + this._hour + ":";
    }
    else{
        TimeString = this._hour + ":";
    }
    if(this._minute < 10){
        TimeString.concat("0" + this._minute + ":");
    }
    else{
        TimeString.concat(this._minute + ":");
    }
    if(this._second < 10){
        TimeString.concat("0" + this._second);
    }
    else{
        TimeString.concat(this._second);
    }

    return TimeString;
}
```

I get "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String" just(!) for the last statemenet: "TimeString.concat(this._second)". 
Why is this happening? and why is this happening only for the last statement when all others pass ok??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everywhere else  you are converting input to string first i.e

```
  TimeString.concat("0" + this._second);
```

But at `TimeString.concat(this._second);` this._second is not string by default. You need to convert it first to string . One way is

```
 "" + this._second
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're building up a string like this, use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenation; it's more efficient and a bit clearer what's going on. In particular, its `append` methods are defined for any types, not just other strings.

(And use Java code conventions: Variable names start with lowercase letters.)